# Views pager not displaying after slideshow image was deleted

Tags: 7, views, paging

Long story short, I followed both of the guides that can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXh8Ng9QNaA

I made a couple of adjustments, however.

1. I set it up as a block instead of a page so I could display other content on the page
2. I published the images so that users could view the full picture when they clicked the links

Everything worked fine until I deleted one of the images in the slideshow (it was a placeholder). Now the pager doesn't display at all for the slideshow.

I've looked on here, Drupal forums, etc., to see if any questions similar to this have been asked before, but I don't seem to be having much luck.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your View settings.

Comment: I'm not sure how detailed or far in you want me to go, but here's the overview: http://imgur.com/a/ctyfE

Comment: did you do [this part](https://youtu.be/sXh8Ng9QNaA?t=14m34s) ?

Comment: Yup. It all worked until I deleted one of the images from the slideshow. https://imgur.com/a/9Wxal

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment because I don't think it properly qualifies as an answer: the problem seemed to sort itself out after I installed an update for either Views.